# Calling -[CALayer setBorderColor:] with an RGB color

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer

Hell again all. I seem to be unable to assign RGBA colors to the setBorderColor method of a layer.

I tried:

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
[l setBorderColor:myColor];
```

Where l is of type CALayer and I get the warning: Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIColor*' to parameter of type 'CGColorRed ('aka 'struct CGColor *'). 
Do you know what the reason may be? The warning appears on the last line. 
On the internet I find this code over and over again, so I thought it should be valid...  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CALayer.borderColor` is defined as

```
@property CGColorRef borderColor;
```

Note that the type here is `CGColorRef`. You're trying to pass a `UIColor*`, which is a different beast. Luckily, `UIColor` has a property that returns a `CGColorRef`. Try using

```
[l setBorderColor:myColor.CGColor];
```